# ORA-01008: not all variables bound - ASP.net Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I get this "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" error in the insert query when i try to insert data into oracle database using GridView footer template to insert the data into the oracle database, i tested the query on the server and it works just fine but when i try to run the app and excute the query using the add button it shows the error

**Grid View Code am using template fields so i can edit the grid view the footer template **

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvmb"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  BackColor="#DEBA84"  BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" Width="60%" style="margin-left: 350px" Height="226px" ShowFooter="True" OnRowCommand="gvmb_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="member_id" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label text='<%# Eval("member_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="member" text='<%# Eval("member_id") %>' runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="member_idfooter"  runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label text='<%# Eval("user_name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uname" text='<%# Eval("user_name") %>' runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                         <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="user_namefooter" runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="address">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label text='<%# Eval("address") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="addres" text='<%# Eval("address") %>' runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                         <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="addressfooter" runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label text='<%# Eval("email_address") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="email" text='<%# Eval("email_address") %>' runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                         <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="email_addressfooter" runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="password">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label text='<%# Eval("password") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="pass" text='<%# Eval("password") %>' runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                         <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="passwordfooter" runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="mobile number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label text='<%# Eval("mob_number") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="mob" text='<%# Eval("mob_number") %>' runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                         <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="mob_numberfooter" runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="edit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" ToolTip="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                              <asp:LinkButton ID="delete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" ToolTip="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>

                        </ItemTemplate> 

                        <FooterTemplate>
                             <asp:LinkButton ID="add" runat="server" CommandName="add" ToolTip="add">add</asp:LinkButton>

                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblsuccess" runat="server" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblerror" runat="server" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

**C# code including the insert event i get the error in the add.ExcuteNonQuery() method**

```
 if (e.CommandName.Equals("add"))
            {
                coon.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO members (member_id, user_name,address ,mob_number,email_address,password ) VALUES (:member_id, :user_name,:address ,:mob_number,:email_address,:password)";
                OleDbCommand add = new OleDbCommand(query, coon);
                add.Parameters.AddWithValue(":member_id", (gvmb.FooterRow.FindControl("member_idfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                add.Parameters.AddWithValue(":user_name", (gvmb.FooterRow.FindControl("user_namefooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                add.Parameters.AddWithValue(":address", (gvmb.FooterRow.FindControl("addressfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                add.Parameters.AddWithValue(":mob_number", (gvmb.FooterRow.FindControl("mob_numberfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                add.Parameters.AddWithValue(":email_address", (gvmb.FooterRow.FindControl("email_addressfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                add.Parameters.AddWithValue(":password", (gvmb.FooterRow.FindControl("passwordfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

                add.ExecuteNonQuery();
                fillmembers();
                lblsuccess.Text = "New Recored Added";
                lblerror.Text = "";
                coon.Close();
            }
```

Comment: I believe the correct syntax uses @ when adding parameters, try changing to this: add.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member_id", ....

Comment: I am using Oracle not SQL so the parameters should be bound using : not @ i think

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to using OracleCommand instead, you can use the OracleParamater specific to Oracle for this to work.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("client", client));
```

Depending on what namespace you have, either Oracle.DataAccess.Client or System.Data.OracleClient, you may use the AddWithValue version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved I just changed the : parameters in the query to ? and it worked i guess there was something wrong with the sequence of the parameters

INSERT INTO members (member_id, user_name,address ,mob_number,email_address,password ) VALUES (?, ?,?,?,?,?)